# Python disaggregation of smart meter data

Tags: python, meter

I am looking for some help with disaggregation of smart meter data, preferably using Python.
I have found a Python module on Github that can be used for this (https://github.com/dssg/wikienergy), but I can not seem to get it to work.  Does anyone have some experience using this module, or can point me to an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I am one of the authors of the linked project. Unfortunately it is not currently maintained and we have no plans to maintain it. As you asked this question a few months ago, you may have already stumbled across https://github.com/nilmtk/nilmtk/, which is likely more stable alternative, but which is also not actively maintained.

Comment: Thx.  I will look into it.